# When I put 'e' character in input type="number " the number is put in the field angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-ngmodel

I need to block the 'e' value that I can put in a input type number so this is my html file:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="money" name="money" required min="0" step="0.01" >
```

in my ts class

```
money:number;
```

Anyone can help me? I want block the possibility to insert the value 'e' in input type number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `keypress` event on the input to prevent the entering of `e`. You'll have to create a method as a handler on your Component Class.

try this:

```
preventE(event) {
  if (event.which === 101) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<input 
  type="number" 
  class="form-control" 
  [(ngModel)]="money" 
  name="money" 
  required 
  min="0" 
  step="0.01" 
  (keypress)="preventE($event)">
```

Comment: the code work yes but  it not perfect because thia code block also character like , . - that I must use in a input type="number"

Comment: need to delete also '+'  sorry but I'm forget it!